# Convolution with additional cosine

Tags: convolution

I want to perform a convolution, but as a complication there is a cosine of the angle between any pair of vectors in the expression:

\begin{equation}
f(\theta^{\prime}) = \int d\theta G(|\theta^{\prime}-\theta|)H(\theta)\cos(2\Theta(\theta^{\prime}-\theta))
\end{equation}

where $\Theta$ is an expression for the angle, and $G$ and $H$ are just some functions.

How can I efficiently compute this integral numerically?

Comment: Also posted on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34254803/102441)

Comment: Convolutions aren't normally done as a double integral - are you sure that shouldn't be $d\theta$ instead of $d^2 \theta$

Comment: You are quite right - thank you

Comment: $\Theta$ is a function too, right?

Comment: Yes, $\Theta$ is a function of the two vectors $\theta$ and $\theta^{\prime}$

Comment: Be clear here - is $\Theta$ a function of _two_ vectors, or a function of the _single_ vector $\theta - \theta'$?

Answer (score 1):

Can you collapse together $\Theta$ and $G$?

$$
    X(\theta) = G(|\theta|)cos(\Theta(\theta))
$$

Then just find $X * H$

Comment: Perhaps this was unclear, perhaps not: but for clarity, $\theta$ is a position vector in the plane here. Confusing notation, my apologies.
The thing I'm struggling with to wrap my head around: $\Theta$ is a function of the *angle* of the vector $\theta$. To use that in a convolution, I think the numerical implementation would need to be evaluated in polar coordinates...

Comment: I don't see how your comment relates to my answer. If you're doing this numerically, you just need to precalculate $G(x^2 + y^2)\cos(\Theta(x, y))$, and convolve that with H (which from your SO post, I assume is a discrete image)